# Can someone explain what this theorem and proof is saying

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

[image]

can someone please explain what the following theorem and proof is saying.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider a *finite* case : if $A_2 \subseteq A_1$, then $A_1 \cup A_2 = A_1$.

Comment: The proof needs the property of set *equality* : $A=B$ **iff** $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$ and the definition of set *inclusion* : $A \subseteq B$ **iff** : if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, for any $x$. The proof consider only one part of the "double" inclusion bec ause the part : $A_1 \subseteq A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \ldots$ is trivial.

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I will first give an example, so you can visualize it. Let $A_1=\{1,2,3\}$, $A_2=\{2,3\}$, $A_3=\{3\}$ Therefore you have that $A_3 \subset A_2 \subset A_1$ and therefore $\bigcup_{i=1}^{3}A_i=A_1$ (since repetition of elements in a set, doesn't count for set cardinality, that is $\{3,3\}=\{3\}$)

If you do this with infinite sets, you will obtain the same result, since $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset ...$ You have that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i= A_1$ as shown in the proof.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem is from measure theory. It talks about monotonicity of sets. If $A_i\subseteq A_j$ whenever $i\geq j$, then it happens that $A_i\cup A_j=A_j$. In particular  $A_2\cup A_1=A_1$. Doing this infinite number of times yields your theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of sets $\{A_n\}$ with $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq\ldots A_n\supseteq\ldots$.

Since, $A_n\subseteq A_1$ for all $n$, $\bigcup A_n\subseteq A_1$, then the other hand $A_1\subseteq\bigcup A_n$.